# integral $\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(2t)}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt$

Tags: integration, contour-integration

I want to compute this integral
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(2t)}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt$$

where $0<b \leq a$.

I have this results
$$I_1=-\frac{ab}{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(2t)}{a^2sin^2(t)+b^2cos^2(t)}dt=\frac{a}{a+b}-\frac{1}{2}$$
But I don't know how to prove this equality.

Which can help me,
Thanks for all.

Comment: Sorry, I asked this question twice, but I received many ideas and  importants tricks. The second post is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364751/how-can-i-prove-the-following-equality?noredirect=1#comment2777151_1364751)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One trick to facilitate analysis is to write

$$\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$$

and

$$\cos^2x=\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}$$

Thus,

$$a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)=\frac{b^2+a^2}{2}+\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}\cos 2t$$

For the integral of interest, we can write

$$\begin{align}
I_1&=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos(2t)}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos t}{\frac{b^2+a^2}{2}+\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}\cos t}dt\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(b^2-a^2)}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos t}{\frac{b^2+a^2}{b^2-a^2}+\cos t}dt\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{(b^2-a^2)}-\frac{b^2+a^2}{(b^2-a^2)^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\frac{b^2+a^2}{b^2-a^2}+\cos t}dt
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

**SPOLIER ALERT**
SCROLL OVER SHADED AREA TO SEE ANSWER

> Starting with the last term $I=\frac{2\pi}{(b^2-a^2)}-\frac{b^2+a^2}{(b^2-a^2)^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\frac{b^2+a^2}{b^2-a^2}+\cos t}dt$, we move to the complex plane by letting $z=e^{it}$.  Then, $I$ becomes $$\begin{align}I&=\frac{2\pi}{(b^2-a^2)}-\frac{b^2+a^2}{(b^2-a^2)^2}\oint_C \frac{-2i}{z^2+2\frac{b^2+a^2}{b^2-a^2}\,z+1}dz\\\\&=\frac{2\pi}{(b^2-a^2)}-\frac{b^2+a^2}{(b^2-a^2)^2}\left(2\pi i \frac{-2i}{-2\frac{2ab}{a^2-b^2}}\right)\\\\&=\frac{2\pi}{(b^2-a^2)}+\frac{2\pi}{ab}\frac{a^2+b^2}{2(a^2-b^2)}\\\\&=\frac{-2\pi}{ab}\left(\frac12 -\frac{a}{a+b}\right)\end{align}$$

---

**NOTE:**

For $I_2=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin(2t)}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt$, enforce the substitution $t= \pi -x$.  Then, we see

$$\begin{align}
I_2&=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin(2t)}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt\\\\
&=\int_{\pi}^{0} \frac{\sin 2(\pi-x)}{a^2\sin^2(\pi-x)+b^2\cos^2(\pi-x)}(-1)dx\\\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{-\sin (2x)}{a^2\sin^2(x)+b^2\cos^2(x)}dx\\\\
&=-I_2
\end{align}$$

Thus, we have $I_2=-I_2$ which, of course, implies $I_2=0$!

Comment: I like the 'spoiler alert'... Vote up!

Comment: @johannesvalks Thanks!  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** First compute 
$$
I=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(2t)}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t)}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt=\int_0^{2\pi}R(\cos(t), \sin(t)) dt
$$
Where $R$ is the rational function given by $$R(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{a^2y^2+b^2x^2}$$
**How to do this?** Put $z=e^{it}=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$, thus 
$$
\cos(t)=Re(z)=\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}, \ \\ \sin(t)=Im(z)=\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}, \\ dz=ie^{it} dt=iz \ dt \Longrightarrow dt=\frac{1}{iz}dz
$$
Then $I$ can be seen as a contour integral, solve it by using residues 
$$
I=\int_0^{2\pi}R(\cos(t), \sin(t)) dt= \int_{|z|=1} R\left(\frac{z+1/z}{2}, \frac{z-1/z}{2i} \right)\frac{1}{iz}dz
$$
**Finally:** Note that 
$$
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos(2t)}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt=\frac{I}{2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Although there is already an accepted answer, I put this answer here, since someone might have use of the "tool" to work with the expression like this before integrating.

The case $a=b$ is trivial, so we assume $a>b$. We write the numerator $\cos 2t$ in the following way:
$$
\cos 2t=\cos^2t-\sin^2t=\alpha\bigl(b^2\cos^2t+a^2\sin^2t\bigr)+(1-\alpha b^2)\cos^2t-(1+\alpha a^2)\sin^2t,
$$
and we'll soon see how to choose $\alpha$ in a good way, where good means that we should get something that we can integrate. Let us first use the trig-one on the $\cos^2 t$ part, to get
$$
\cos 2t = \alpha\bigl(b^2\cos^2t+a^2\sin^2t\bigr)+(1-\alpha b^2)-\bigl[(1-\alpha b^2)+(1+\alpha a^2)\bigr]\sin^2 t.
$$
Now, we choose $\alpha$ so that the constant in brackets is zero, i.e.
$$
(1-\alpha b^2)+(1+\alpha a^2)=0 \iff \alpha=\frac{2}{b^2-a^2}.
$$
This gives
$$
\cos 2t = \frac{2}{b^2-a^2}(b^2\cos^2t+a^2\sin^2t)-\frac{a^2+b^2}{b^2-a^2}.
$$
Now comes the fun part. We can write the integrand
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\cos 2t}{b^2\cos^2t+a^2\sin^2t}&=\frac{2}{b^2-a^2}-\frac{a^2+b^2}{b^2-a^2}\frac{1}{b^2\cos^2t+a^2\sin^2t}\\
&=\frac{2}{b^2-a^2}-\frac{a^2+b^2}{b^2-a^2}\frac{1}{b^2\cot^2t+a^2}\frac{1}{\sin^2t}.
\end{aligned}
$$
This is easy to integrate,
$$
\int \frac{\cos 2t}{b^2\cos^2t+a^2\sin^2t}\,dt = \frac{2t}{b^2-a^2}-\frac{a^2+b^2}{b^2-a^2} \frac{1}{ab}\text{arccot}\,\Bigl(\frac{b\cot t}{a}\Bigr).
$$
I'm sure you can insert the limits and get the result from this. I get
$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos 2t}{b^2\cos^2t+a^2\sin^2t}\,dt=\frac{(a-b)\pi}{ab(a+b)}.
$$