# How can I prove the following equality

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following equality :

$$I_1=-\frac{ab}{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos(2t)}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt=\frac{a}{a+b}-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$I_2=-\frac{ab}{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(2t)}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt=0$$

where $0 <b \leq a$.

I used the residues but I could not prove this equality

Comment: Try $t=\pi/2 + u$

Comment: For $I_2$ , let $\sin t = x $, then you can calculate the integral. Note that $I_1$ has the same form with $I_2$ if you let $t = \pi/2 +u$ as @MichaelGaluza 's recommendation.

Comment: Looks like you asked this a couple of months ago … http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306776/integral-int-0-pi-frac-cos2ta2-sin2tb2-cos2tdt . It is not nice when you ask the same question twice in this site, you can always manage to drag more attention to your first question...

Comment: @LeoSera Evidently the OP did not receive a satisfactory answer.  Perhaps, you can describe a way to "drag more attention" to the original post.  I believe that the question is legitimate since the OP was given one wrong answer (the posted solution for $I_1$ is not correct) and thus should not be closed.

Comment: @Dr.MV First of all there is no answers in the OP´s first question, just a hint, which I think may lead to a correct solution, I don't see why it is wrong. Nevertheless it is clear the OP wasn't satisfied with the hint. Second of all you can always edit your old question, adding for example the $I_2$ integral to put your question in the active ones and receive new visits …. So no need to re-ask practically the same question

Comment: You are right, I posted this question in the month ago,  I received one  suggestion, but when I r-ask here , I received many answer and the all is right.
want you delete this question?  
Give me the right solution because I'am new in this forum and I didn't know the law...

Comment: Sorry, I asked this question twice, but I received many ideas and  importants tricks. The second post is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306776/integral-int-0-pi-frac-cos2ta2-sin2tb2-cos2tdt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$I=I_1+iI_2.$$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&-\frac{ab}{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{2it}}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt\\
&=&-\frac{ab}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{it}}{a^2\frac{1-\cos t}{2}+b^2\frac{1+\cos t}{2}}dt\\
&=&-\frac{ab}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{it}}{(a^2+b^2)+(b^2-a^2)\cos t}dt\\
&=&-\frac{ab}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)+(b^2-a^2)\frac12(z+\frac{1}{z})}dz\\
&=&-\frac{ab}{\pi i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{z}{2(a^2+b^2)z+(b^2-a^2)(z^2+1)}dz\\
&=&-\frac{ab}{\pi i}(2\pi i)\text{Res}\left(\frac{z}{2(a^2+b^2)z+(b^2-a^2)(z^2+1)},\frac{a-b}{a+b}\right)\\
&=&-\frac{ab}{\pi i}2\pi i\frac{a-b}{4ab(a+b)}\\
&=&\frac{b-a}{2(a+b)}\end{eqnarray}
and hence
$$ I_1=\frac{b-a}{2(a+b)}, I_2=0. $$

Comment: Way to go !! +1 . How did you managed to see that the only pole inside $|z|=1$ was in fact $z_0=\frac{a-b}{a+b}$ ?

Comment: Note that $2(a^2+b^2)z+(b^2-a^2)(z^2+1)=0$ has two roots $z_1=\frac{a-b}{a+b},z_2=\frac{a+b}{a-b}$. It is easy to see $|z_1|<1,|z_2|>1$. Done.

Comment: Thanks !! Also note that your answer agrees with the one of @Dr.MV, since 
$$
\frac{b-a}{2(a+b)} = \frac12 - \frac{a}{a+b}
$$
So in fact it looks like the OP has the wrong answer by a factor of $-1$.

Comment: @LeoSera, you are right.

Comment: Looks like mine. ;-)))

Comment: @Dr.MV, I put two together.

Comment: @xpaul Yes, I see that; well done!  There was a typo (you omitted a $2\pi i$ before the "Res") and some formatting that I edited.  I hope that you don't mind.

Comment: @Dr.MV, of course, I don't.

Comment: @Dr.MV, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One trick to facilitate analysis is to write

$$\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$$

and

$$\cos^2x=\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}$$

Thus,

$$a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)=\frac{b^2+a^2}{2}+\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}\cos 2t$$

For the integral of interest, we can write

$$\begin{align}
I_1&=-\frac{ab}{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\cos(2t)}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt\\\\
&=-\frac{ab}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos t}{\frac{b^2+a^2}{2}+\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}\cos t}dt\\\\
&=-\frac{ab}{2\pi(b^2-a^2)}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos t}{\frac{b^2+a^2}{b^2-a^2}+\cos t}dt\\\\
&=-\frac{ab}{(b^2-a^2)}+\frac{ab(b^2+a^2)}{2\pi(b^2-a^2)^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\frac{b^2+a^2}{b^2-a^2}+\cos t}dt
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

**SPOLIER ALERT**
SCROLL OVER SHADED AREA TO SEE ANSWER

> Starting with the last term $I_1=-\frac{ab}{(b^2-a^2)}+\frac{ab(b^2+a^2)}{2\pi(b^2-a^2)^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\frac{b^2+a^2}{b^2-a^2}+\cos t}dt$, we move to the complex plane by letting $z=e^{it}$.  Then, $I_1$ becomes $$\begin{align}I_1&=-\frac{ab}{(b^2-a^2)}+\frac{ab(b^2+a^2)}{2\pi(b^2-a^2)^2}\oint_C \frac{-2i}{z^2+2\frac{b^2+a^2}{b^2-a^2}\,z+1}dz\\\\&=-\frac{ab}{(b^2-a^2)}+\frac{ab(b^2+a^2)}{2\pi(b^2-a^2)^2}\left(2\pi i \frac{-2i}{-2\frac{2ab}{a^2-b^2}}\right)\\\\&=-\frac{ab}{(b^2-a^2)}-\frac{a^2+b^2}{2(a^2-b^2)}\\\\&=\frac12 -\frac{a}{a+b}\end{align}$$which differs from the posted answer by a factor of $-1$.  For $a=2$ and $b=1$, Wolfram Alpha confirms the value of the integral as $-1/6$ agreeing with the answer herein, whereas the posted answer is $+1/6$.

---

For $I_2$, enforce the substitution $t= \pi -x$.  Then, we see

$$\begin{align}
I_2&=\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin(2t)}{a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)}dt\\\\
&=\int_{\pi}^{0} \frac{\sin 2(\pi-x)}{a^2\sin^2(\pi-x)+b^2\cos^2(\pi-x)}(-1)dx\\\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{-\sin (2x)}{a^2\sin^2(x)+b^2\cos^2(x)}dx\\\\
&=-I_2
\end{align}$$

Thus, we have $I_2=-I_2$ which, of course, implies $I_2=0$ as expected!

Comment: Looks that the other answer given by @xpaul also agrees with yours, so in fact the OP has an incorrect answer. 
$$
\frac{b-a}{2(a+b)} = \frac12 - \frac{a}{a+b}
$$

Comment: @achaire You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @achaire Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @Dr.MV  I am very glad for your interest, you can improve your answer but I don't understand your last comment...

Comment: @Achaire Which comment?  I was asking how I can improve my answer so that it would be more useful for you.

Comment: @Dr.MV Your answer is correct and clear, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

For $I_2$, one way is to use
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(a^2\sin^2(t)+b^2\cos^2(t)\right)=2a^2\sin t\cos t-2b^2\cos t\sin t=(a^2-b^2)\sin(2t).$$